# Using android native button icons

Tags: android

am i allowed (legally) to use graphics/icons from the android source for a commercial application, in order to blend in nicely with the android look&feel?
i am talking specifically about the plus/minus buttons from the edit_contacts activity in the contacts application.
OR: is there a way to let a button look like (ie with a style) these buttons without copying the .png - files?

trying to use `android:background="@android:drawable/btn_circle"` gives me `Error: Resource is not public.`
Does this answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, IANAL, but as far as I can tell, all files in the Contacts application directory are licensed under [Apache License version 2](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html), which seems to mean that as long as you respect the license, and don't infringe on trademarks, you can do pretty much what you want with the project.

At the Apache project's [licenses page](http://www.apache.org/licenses/) you can find a FAQ and a short summary of APL v2. There is also a [page on how to apply](http://www.apache.org/dev/apply-license.html) the license.

If this is incorrect, please let me know!